# stop visual studio 17 compile when i hit a bad constexpr if branch

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, template-meta-programming, c++17, if-constexpr

Is there any way to force the compiler to fail if a constexpr if branch is not supposed to be hit?

this code below explains it all better than I could:

```
template<unsigned int number_base>
class arithmetic_type
{
    if constexpr(number_base == 0 || number_base == 1)
    {
        //hey, compiler! fail this compilation please
    }
    else
    {
        //go on with class implementation
    }

}
```

Comment: `static_assert(1==0)` ?

Comment: What is the point of constexpr branching if one branch is not supposed to be hit? Just put branch condition into `static_assert`.

Comment: I don't know how I didn't think of static assert

Comment: @tobi303: Not sure with `constrexpr if` but `static_assert(1==0)` (as `static_assert(false)`) would be invalid in regular template method, as it should be able to have a valid template.

Comment: @Jarod42 I never used `constexpr` so I wasnt sure either. Barrys answer explains it quite nicely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [`static_assert()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert). In this case, you can drop the `if constexpr` and just assert directly:

```
template<unsigned int number_base>
class arithmetic_type
{
    static_assert(number_base != 0 && number_base != 1); // or >= 2, since unsigned
    //go on with class implementation
};
```

But generally, there may be places where you just need `static_assert(false)`. But that is ill-formed, that assertion would always trigger because it's a non-dependent conditional. In that case, you need to provide something that looks dependent but actually isn't:

```
// always false, but could hypothetically be specialized to be true, but 
// nobody should ever do this
template <class T> struct always_false : std::false_type { };

static_assert(always_false<SomeDependentType>::value);
```

Comment: Does the `static_assert(false)` is also invalid in constexpr if ?

Comment: @Jarod42 Yeah. `if constexpr` prevents the discarded substatement from being *instantiated*. But there isn't anything that needs instantiating in `static_assert(false)`.